In Android Studio, flutter project hot reload is not working when saving files
Steps to Reproduce
In Android Studio, hot reload is not working when saving files.
Version info
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-x64, locale en-CN)
    • Flutter version 3.22.2 on channel stable at /Users/web-j/Library/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 761747bfc5 (5 weeks ago), 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
    • Engine revision edd8546116
    • Dart version 3.4.3
    • DevTools version 2.34.3
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/web-j/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/web-j/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google
    Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.1.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 74.0.4
    • Dart plugin version 231.9161.14

[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.92.0

[!] Proxy Configuration
    • HTTP_PROXY is set
    ! NO_PROXY is not set

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • PBEM00 (mobile) • 3024661 • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos   • darwin-x64    • macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-x64

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Android Studio info
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-241.18034.62.2411.12071903, built on July 11, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.4.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
  ide.instant.shutdown=false
  ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
  debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
  ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  com.markskelton.one-dark-theme (5.11.0)
  Dart (241.17890.8)
  com.jetbrains.gerryPurpleTheme (2024.1.0601)
  com.intellij.plugins.vscodekeymap (241.14494.150)
  com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.15)
  com.github.dinbtechit.vscodetheme (1.10.10)
  ai.codegeex.plugin (2.12.0-223)
  io.flutter (80.0.2)

Plugin:
Dart: 241.17890.8
Flutter: 80.0.2

It's worth mentioning that the shortcut key for hot reload is functional.

Update the Dart and Flutter plugin versions in Android Studio, but there are no changes; however, the shortcut keys work normally. But on my other M2 Max machine, neither the shortcut keys nor saving function properly.
I hope it can work correctly.
